# Present view controller from helper methods

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently writing a helper to wrap my alamofire request. And was wondering how do I presentalertviewcontroller when I receive a message from my helper class, or how to communicate from my helper class to my view controller that I am supposed to present this alertviewcontroller?

The following is what I have, do advise anything if you see me did wrong as this is my first time writing an api wrapper.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SVProgressHUD

class AlamoHelper: NSObject {

    class func request(method: Alamofire.Method, url: URLStringConvertible, var parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil) -> Alamofire.Request {

        parameters!["os"] = "ios"
        if let versionString = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
            parameters!["v"] = versionString
        }
        SVProgressHUD.showWithMaskType(SVProgressHUDMaskType.Black)
        return Alamofire.request(method, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)

            .responseJSON {
                response in

                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    if let message = json["message"].string {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: json["subject"].stringValue, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(okAction)
                    }

                    if json["status"].intValue == 401 {
                        AppDelegate.isLoggedIn = false
                        AppDelegate.removeCookies()
                    }

                    break
                case .Failure:
                    break
                }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pseudocode :

1. Write a constructor in your helper class which accepts your view
   controller object .

   ```
      -(void)initWithController:(YourViewController *)_ctr
      {
        ctr = _ctr;
      }
   ```
2. Write a method to present view controller in your view controller class as goToNextVc().
3. Invoke the goToNextVc() method from helper class using same instance that you get from the view controller.

Comment: Any advice to write step 1? Cause it may be a table view controller or a tabbar view controller right? Again sorry if this sounds dumb but I'm really a bit new.

Comment: @Happiehappie: No , you need to write the constructor in the helper class .  I mean init method . I have updated my answer. Please convert the code into swift .

Answer (score 0):

Use [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) to pass information from `AlamoHelper` to caller `UIViewController`.

So,

1. create a protocol with some method passing useful information like alert being presented etc.
2. create a delegate property on
       `AlamoHelper`.
3. while instantiating `AlamoHelper` object from your
       `UIViewController`, set `self` as delegate on `AlamoHelper` object.
4. Implement protocol method in your `UIViewController`.
5. finally, once request come back, from `AlamoHelper` class, call the protocol method on delegate object.